# Grouping elements based on common element to form a json array of objects

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

im getting my data as whole json,but i expect it to be grouped based on a common element among the result itself

**Data from query**

| firststring | secondstring | thirdstring |
| --- | --- | --- |
| My Account | MyAccount | Menu1 |
| My Cart | MyFavourites | Menu1 |
| My Status | Status | Menu1 |
| Orders | orders | Menu2 |
| Damage Claim | DamageClaim | Menu2 |

**my bean class**

```
    public class CommonThreeString implements Serializable{

        private String firstString;
        private String secondString;
        private String thirdString;
        
        public String getFirstString() {
            return firstString;
        }
        public void setFirstString(String firstString) {
            this.firstString = firstString;
        }
        public String getSecondString() {
            return secondString;
        }
        public void setSecondString(String secondString) {
            this.secondString = secondString;
        }
        public String getThirdString() {
            return thirdString;
        }
        public void setThirdString(String thirdString) {
            this.thirdString = thirdString;
        }
    }
```

**My controller**

```
        @PostMapping("getMenuList")
    public String getMenuList() throws ServiceException {
        ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String json = null;
        try {
            json = ow.writeValueAsString(iService.getMenuList());
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        }

        return json;
    }
```

**service implementation**

```
        public List<CommonThreeString> getMenuList() throws ServiceException {
    
        List<CommonTwoLongThreeString> menuList = null;
        try {
            menuList =  Impl.getMenuListByPortalId(Long.valueOf("input"));
            //query works done here//
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
        }
        return menuList;
    }
```

here im getting output as

```
 [   
      {
        "firstString": "My Account",
        "secondString": "MyAccount",
        "thirdString": "Menu1"
      },
      {
        "firstString": "My Cart",
        "secondString": "MyFavourites",
        "thirdString": "Menu1"
      },
      {
        "firstString": "My Status",
        "secondString": "Status",
        "thirdString": "Menu1"
      },
      {
        "firstString": "orders",
        "secondString": "orders",
        "thirdString": "Menu2"
      },
      {
        "firstString": "Damage Claim",
        "secondString": "DamageClaim",
        "thirdString": "Menu2"
      }
    ]
```

The output im expecting

```
    Menu1
    [   
      {
        "firstString": "My Account",
        "secondString": "MyAccount",
        --"thirdString": "Menu1"
      },
      {
        "firstString": "My Cart",
        "secondString": "MyFavourites",
        --"thirdString": "Menu1"
      },
      {
        "firstString": "My Status",
        "secondString": "Status",
        --"thirdString": "Menu1"
      }
      ]
      Menu2
      [
      {
        "firstString": "orders",
        "secondString": "orders",
        --"thirdString": "Menu2"
      },
      {
        "firstString": "Damage Claim",
        "secondString": "DamageClaim",
        --"thirdString": "Menu2"
      }
    ]
```

the third String need to be the grouping factor

im want to group properly like the above thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import com.google.gson.*;

public class TestJson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonString = null;
        try {
            jsonString = "[\n"
                    + "    {\n"
                    + "        \"firstString\": \"My Account\",\n"
                    + "        \"secondString\": \"MyAccount\",\n"
                    + "        \"thirdString\": \"Menu1\"\n"
                    + "    },\n"
                    + "    {\n"
                    + "        \"firstString\": \"My Cart\",\n"
                    + "        \"secondString\": \"MyFavourites\",\n"
                    + "        \"thirdString\": \"Menu1\"\n"
                    + "    },\n"
                    + "    {\n"
                    + "        \"firstString\": \"My Status\",\n"
                    + "        \"secondString\": \"Status\",\n"
                    + "        \"thirdString\": \"Menu1\"\n"
                    + "    },\n"
                    + "    {\n"
                    + "        \"firstString\": \"orders\",\n"
                    + "        \"secondString\": \"orders\",\n"
                    + "        \"thirdString\": \"Menu2\"\n"
                    + "    },\n"
                    + "    {\n"
                    + "        \"firstString\": \"Damage Claim\",\n"
                    + "        \"secondString\": \"DamageClaim\",\n"
                    + "        \"thirdString\": \"Menu2\"\n"
                    + "    }\n"
                    + "]";
            
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


            com.google.gson.JsonArray dataArray = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonArray();

            HashMap<String, List<CommonThreeString>> groupByFieldMap = new HashMap<String, List<CommonThreeString>>();

            for (JsonElement element : dataArray) {
                String groupField = element.getAsJsonObject().get("thirdString").getAsString();
                String firstStr = element.getAsJsonObject().get("firstString").getAsString();
                String secondStr = element.getAsJsonObject().get("secondString").getAsString();
                String thirdStr = element.getAsJsonObject().get("thirdString").getAsString();
                if (groupByFieldMap.containsKey(groupField)) {
                    groupByFieldMap.get(groupField).add(new CommonThreeString(firstStr, secondStr, thirdStr));
                } else {
                    ArrayList<CommonThreeString> emptyList = new ArrayList<CommonThreeString>();
                    emptyList.add(new CommonThreeString(firstStr, secondStr, thirdStr));
                    groupByFieldMap.put(groupField, emptyList);
                }
            }

            StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
            mapper.writeValue(result, groupByFieldMap);
            System.out.println(result.toString());
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception "+e.getStackTrace());
        }

    }

}
```

Ref Here : how to do it

[Grouping Json response with keys in java - android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39204438/grouping-json-response-with-keys-in-java-android-studio)

Seems to be a duplicate ticket